# Weird Characters in gmusicbrowser Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, special-characters, gmusicbrowser

one problem. When the shimmer desktop theme in gmusicbrowser in Xubuntu 13.10, i have weird characters like the letter A acting as separators between artist, year and album. Any idea what could i do about it to make it look normal?

[image]

Comment: Looks like UTF-8 encoded data misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1 encoded, or something like that.

Comment: Any way i could fix that?

Comment: I found this patch, but don't know how to apply it :/ https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gmusicbrowser/1.1.10-2

Comment: That seems like problem with Language Support. Go to Settings and click 'Language Support'. If there is any problem, you will be asked to install necessary language files. Then all will become normal.

Comment: Done that rainlover, but it still doesn't help. As i said, the patch i posted should work, but i don't know how to apply it...